# How to use custom function in jquery chaining

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to make something like this:

```
function hideThisObject(objectName){
    $(objectName).css({
        "transition":"200ms",
        "opacity":"0"
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(objectName).remove();
    },250);
}

$('p').hideThisObject(this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use jquery `$.fn.*` to declaring jquery custom function.

```js
$.fn.customFunc = function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
};

$("div").customFunc();
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```